# Returning the position of a number in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of numbers say

let numbers = [4,7,2,0,9];

I want the numbers array to be mapped based on the size of the number in the array and return its position. I need the output to look like this

numbers = [3,4,2,1,5];

thank you

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the array, and sort it ascending, and map it to pairs of `[num, index + 1]`. Convert the array of pairs to an object (`position`).

Now map the original array, and take the position of each number from the `positions` object.

```js
const numbers = [4,7,2,0,9];

const positions = Object.fromEntries(
  [...numbers]
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .map((num, index) => [num, index + 1])
);

const result = numbers.map(num => positions[num]);

console.log(result);
```

You can use a Map instead of an object, by replacing `Object.fromEntries()` with the Map's constructor:

```js
const numbers = [4,7,2,0,9];

const positions = new Map(
  [...numbers]
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .map((num, index) => [num, index + 1])
);

const result = numbers.map(num => positions.get(num));

console.log(result);
```

For you need to handle multiple identical values, reduce the array to a Map, and add the current index. When you map the original array, take the value's index from the start of each entry's value:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0];

const positions = [...numbers]
  .sort((a, b) => a - b)
  .reduce((acc, v, i) => acc.set(v, [...acc.get(v) ?? [], i + 1]), new Map())

const result = numbers.map(num => positions.get(num).shift());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I saved a map and fromEntries and a spread

Comment: Good idea. Added. the spread is instead of the slice, to clone the original array.

Comment: I still save a map ;)

Comment: But your map action is O(n^2). The usual memory vs run complexity.

Comment: what if i what to map it the other way round. meaning from largest to smallest

Comment: Sort descending instead - `.sort((a, b) => b - a)`

Comment: i noticed it returns the last index for an array with the same numbers. for example numbers = [0,0,0]    returns [3,3,3]

Answer (score 1):

You mean this which is the simplest of the answers so far

It will do the job on arrays that are not in the thousands. If large, go with a lookup Map

```js
const arr = [4,7,2,0,9]

const indicii = arr.slice(0).sort((a,b) => a-b); // copy and sort
const res = arr.map(arrItem=> indicii.indexOf(arrItem)+1); // map indicii plus 1

console.log(res)
```